# A good resource to get the most out of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I was wondering if any one could offer me some advice as to the best resources out there (ideally books) on google analytics. I have a basic understanding but have a lot of room for improvement.

The following book "Advanced Web Metrics with Google Analytics" by Brian Clifton, appears to be a good starting but but is already quite dated, even though published in march 2010.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a lot from Google's own videos:
http://www.youtube.com/googleanalytics?hl=en

There is a blog, with an index of resources:
http://analytics.blogspot.com/

They also have an education area: 
http://www.google.com/analytics/education.html

Comment: they seem like great resources. I may buy the book i mentioned and glean as much as i can from the above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

another good resource to get you started is avinash kaushik's blog (THE analytics guru, now employed at google, handling google analytics):

[Avinash Kaushik's Blog: Occam's Razor](http://www.kaushik.net)